# Event on click the row header of a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid, datagridrowheader

In my WPF-Project, I have a `DataGrid`. I want to get an Event when the user clicks on the `RowHeader`, but I cannot find one. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can handle OnLoadingRow of your dataGrid and set RowHeader. sth like this:

```
protected override void OnLoadingRow(DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = e.Row;
    if (e.Row.GetType() != typeof(DataGridRowHeader))
    {
        DataGridRowHeader header=new DataGridRowHeader();
        header.Click+=new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(header_Click);
        row.Header = header;
    }
     base.OnLoadingRow(e);
}
```

Comment: Very nice, but how do I get the row index aswell when clicking the row header?

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are manipulating the RowHeaderStyle, then,

```
        <Setter Property="RowHeaderStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown"
                                 Handler="OnGridRowHeaderClick" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```